# I think about adding a second hard drive to my laptop

Tags: installation, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Z580 laptop and I want to replace the DVD drive with a 16GB SSD drive. Now I have just 2 partitions on my hard drive ( / and /home), after adding the SSD drive I want to use it like the current partition mounted in / and my HDD like the current partition mounted in /home. Is it possible? Has somebody tried this method to use Ubuntu?

Comment: You can certainly do as you describe. It may be easiest to simply back up your data in /home reinstall. You otherwise have to move you data, edit /etc/fstab, and update grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a second drive in an old tower, with `/` and the `swap file` on a forty gig `/dev/sda` and `/home` on a 300 gig `/dev/sdb`. Works fine. (It's a salvaged system pieced together from scraps.) However, a second hard drive on a laptop would be a fearsome drain on your battery.

Comment: The battery isn't a problem. I write lines of code day by day and for me the most important is the speed of work

Comment: About swap I think that will not be necessary, I will add 4GB to the current 4GB, it's enough.

Comment: Is the existing drive also an SSD, or is one a traditional "disk" drive? Never having attempted what you're thinking of doing, it's not obvious to me that having the system files on an SSD and the user files on a magnetic drive would be noticeably faster. Interesting question, though.