# Replacing hardrive (laptop)

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

My laptop has 2 HD's. One broken, one not broken.

Can I replace a HDD with a SSD? I noticed by using the smartctl command that my SSD is TWICE as fast! And my HDD is broken so I want to replace it with a SSD? But Im scared that they use different cables or the SSD wont fit into the laptop? Should I just be safe and by the same exact HDD that I had in the first place?

My plan was to buy another SSD (INTEL SSDSC2CW240A3) and replace the broken HDD (WDC WD10JPVT-55A1YT0)

> > This question --> [I think about adding a second hard drive to my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427151/i-think-about-adding-a-second-hard-drive-to-my-laptop) is similar but doesnt seem solved :(

EDIT: End game is clearly to install ubuntu on the new drive. I hope others are helped by this :)

Comment: You already have a SATA 2.5" SSD in the laptop, so it is highly likely you will be able to replace your disk drive with another SSD. Since you already have an SSD, you could just open the laptop and see if it fits. I expect it will.

Comment: Lets say I open the laptop and disconnect both drives, then attempt to connect the SSD to where the HDD was. If that works then Im good to replace the HDD with a SDD?

Comment: Yes, you do not even need to boot it, just check that it physically fits and the cables are ok.

Comment: I wish your comment was posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a SATA 2.5" SSD in the laptop, so it is highly likely you will be able to replace your disk drive with another SSD. Since you already have an SSD, you could just open the laptop and see if it fits. I expect it will. You do not even need to boot it, just check that it physically fits and the cables are ok.

The problem of fitting a hard drive to a laptop is that sizing of the drive bays varies between different models of laptop. There are five different 2.5" hard drive form factors, each with the different heights  (5mm, 7mm, 9.5mm, 12.5mm, 15mm, see [Hard disk drive form factors on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Form_factors)) The internal bays of  laptops are designed only for a specific maximum height.

There are some other things to watch out for.

- Older laptops may only support PATA connectors, and modern SSDs are SATA.
- You might not get the full speed from a SATA drive if you laptop does not support the latest SATA standard.
- You might not have a regular 2.5" hard drive bay. Some ultraportables use 1.8" drives, some modern systems are using [Mini-SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA%20%28mSATA%29) cards, some are using PCIe SSDs, and soon some will be using [M.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) cards.

Comment: As usual i wish I could select two answers as accepted :( but im picking yours because of your original comment. Ok im off to open up my laptop, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SSD instead of normal HDD as long as it has the same form factor 2.5 inches. The cabling is the same to all HDD. Nowadays most HDD use SATA cabling

Comment: yer that should work any way  as well what cioby23 said

Comment: It is not true that all 2.5" drives have the same form factor: see [Hard disk drive form factors on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Form_factors) - there are five different possible heights (5mm 7mm 9.5mm 12.5mm 15mm) and the internal bays of some laptops are designed only for a specific maximum height.

Comment: Both models SSD (INTEL SSDSC2CW240A3)  the HDD (WDC WD10JPVT-55A1YT0) have same weight of 9.5mm so there shouldn't be any issue replacing the WDC drive with the Intel SSD.

Comment: You really outdid yourself by providing me with that last bit of info cioby23, thanks.. I could not find it by search engine-ing.